# TestNG - ERROR - Java - MAC

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, command, testng

Cannot find working solution to this issue, I understand it has been asked before.

Using Eclipse on Mac, TestNG with Java.
Eclipse runs test suite perfectly within IDE.
When trying to run via command line, I run into the following error:

```
    [TestNG] [ERROR] 
    Cannot find class in classpath: firefoxScripts.SmallRwyLengthChange
```

Here is a screen shot of the IDE environment:
Here is the folder structure from finder:

[Screen shot of Finder's folder structure, and eclipse view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpflU.png)

from terminal, here is the "Learn-Automation/.classpath" file I have been editing:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/bryan.lee/Documents/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.testng.TESTNG_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="bin" path="/Users/bryan.lee/Documents/workspace/Learn-Automation/bin/firefoxScripts/SmallRwyLengthChange.class"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/bryan.lee/Documents/workspace/Learn-Automation/lib/jcommander-1.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/bryan.lee/Documents/workspace/Learn-Automation/lib/selenium-html-runner-3.0.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/bryan.lee/Documents/workspace/Learn-Automation/lib/testng-6.9.9.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/bryan.lee/Documents/workspace/Learn-Automation/lib/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
    </classpath>
```

Finally, the command I run to try and initialize the test case

```
    java -cp /Users/bryan.lee/Documents/workspace/Learn-Automation/lib/testng-6.9.9.jar:/Users/bryan.lee/Documents/workspace/Learn-Automation/lib/jcommander-1.7.jar org.testng.Testng testng.xml
```

To me, the class path is properly set so i'm not sure why it won't detect the class "smallrwylengthchange". And like I stated, it runs perfectly fine in the Eclipse IDE. So simply converting to command line makes me think I am missing something small, like maybe file location? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to tell which command your Eclipse IDE executes?

Comment: I am not that familiar with Eclipse, the console has this before running the log of the TestNG:

/private/var/folders/wj/hf7_2fk163l006nxqnm30s05k61rx8/T/testng-eclipse--1232541245/testng-customsuite.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command line contains TestNG dependencies but where are your classes?

Try with:

> java -cp /Users/bryan.lee/Documents/workspace/Learn-Automation/bin/:/Users/bryan.lee/Documents/workspace/Learn-Automation/lib/testng-6.9.9.jar:/Users/bryan.lee/Documents/workspace/Learn-Automation/lib/jcommander-1.7.jar org.testng.Testng testng.xml

Comment: Great point, I copied the wrong command in. However my older command was including the Class file down to the .class extension. I believe this is wrong, and have realized the issue. +1 for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution, i guess my .classpath file was wrong.

did the following steps:

1. cd into the folder that has "testng.xml"
2. export classpath command with the Selenium-server.jar, and the testng-6.9.9.jar, as well as the LOCATION of the class file "/bin". Previously I had been including the entire file and that was not working, just the folder of the class and it seems to work. Code below separated at ":" for readability

   ```
   export CLASSPATH=/Users/bryan.lee/Documents/workspace/Learn-Automation/lib/testng-6.9.9.jar
   :/Users/bryan.lee/Documents/workspace/Learn-Automation/lib/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar
   :/Users/bryan.lee/Documents/workspace/Learn-Automation/bin
   ```